# Erro: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, classes, static

Esse código ta dando erro:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Quando eu tiro o `static` do main não parece os avisos no Netbeans, mas quando compilo dá erro porque falta `static`. O que faço? Como eu rodo isso?

package Poo2At2;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {
    
    public ArrayList<Filme> filme = new ArrayList<Filme>(11);
    public ArrayList<Aula> aula = new ArrayList<Aula>(11);
    public ArrayList<Classe> classe = new ArrayList<Classe>(11);
    public Somador somador = new Somador();
        
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(somador.somar(this.filme));
        System.out.println(somador.somar(this.aula));
        System.out.println(somador.somar(this.classe));
        
    }

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Faça o que a mensagem de erro mostra que está errado. Se ela diz que há variável não estática é porque precisa que a variável seja estática, certo? Então torne as variáveis estáticas, afinal elas são acessadas em um método estático então só pode acessar variáveis estáticas, as variáveis do jeito que estão aí só poderiam ser acessadas instanciando a classe `Main` e acessar através desse objeto.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static ArrayList<Filme> filme = new ArrayList<Filme>(11);
    public static ArrayList<Aula> aula = new ArrayList<Aula>(11);
    public static ArrayList<Classe> classe = new ArrayList<Classe>(11);
    public static Somador somador = new Somador();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(somador.somar(filme));
        System.out.println(somador.somar(aula));
        System.out.println(somador.somar(classe));
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/StaticMembers.java).

Na verdade esse conceito de ter o método `main()` na mesma classe que ter listas que faz alguma coisa pode até funcionar, mas está conceitualmente errado. Se treinar o erro será isso que aprenderá, então sugiro usar uma metodologia de aprendizado mais estruturada que mostre como fazer, tentativa e erro treina mais o erro. Não posso falar de outros problemas porque não vi o código todo, mas há indícios que tem outros erros só lendo ese trecho, pode estar treinado vários conceitos de forma errada.

Answer (score 0):

Entenda o modificador `static`. Uma definição seria de que quando declaramos uma variável como static, ela passa a ser um atributo da classe e não da instância. Também podemos pensar nessa variável como um atributo global de uma classe.

Veja um exemplo:

Classe com 2 atributos um estatico e outro não.

```
 public class ClasseComAtributoStatic {
        
        public static int contadorStatic;
        public int contadorInstacia;
        
        public ClasseComAtributoStatic() {
            contadorStatic++;
            contadorInstacia++;
        }
        
    }
```

Classe de teste.

```
public class TesteStatic {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClasseComAtributoStatic classeComAtributoStatic = new ClasseComAtributoStatic();
    System.out.println("1- Atributo static (contadorStatic): " + classeComAtributoStatic.contadorStatic);
    System.out.println("2- Atributo instancia  (contadorInstacia): " + classeComAtributoStatic.contadorInstacia);
    
    ClasseComAtributoStatic classeComAtributoStatic2 = new ClasseComAtributoStatic();
    System.out.println("3- Atributo static (contadorStatic): " + classeComAtributoStatic2.contadorStatic);
    System.out.println("4- Atributo instancia (contadorInstacia): " + classeComAtributoStatic2.contadorInstacia);
    
    ClasseComAtributoStatic classeComAtributoStatic3 = new ClasseComAtributoStatic();
    System.out.println("3- Atributo static (contadorStatic): " + classeComAtributoStatic3.contadorStatic);
    System.out.println("4- Atributo instancia (contadorInstacia): " + classeComAtributoStatic3.contadorInstacia);
    
    
    System.out.println("Reimprimindo atributo static (contadorStatic) da primeira isntacia: " + classeComAtributoStatic.contadorStatic);

}
```

}

Resultado da execução da class TesteStatic

```
1- Atributo static (contadorStatic): 1
2- Atributo instancia  (contadorInstacia): 1
3- Atributo static (contadorStatic): 2
4- Atributo instancia (contadorInstacia): 1
3- Atributo static (contadorStatic): 3
4- Atributo instancia (contadorInstacia): 1
Reimprimindo atributo static (contadorStatic) da primeira isntacia: 3
```

Vamos entender o que aconteceu aqui. Eu quero saber quantas vezes a minha classe `ClasseComAtributoStatic` foi instanciada pelo construtor que criei. Sabendo que atributo statico pertence a classe e não de cada instância, toda vez que o construtor for executado o atributo estatico `contadorStatic` é incrementado e "mantem"  o seu valor até o  final da execução. O atributo `contadorInstacia` também é incrementado mas ele pertence a cada instancia do objeto, sendo assim seu valor fica sempre em 1. Ou seja, comparando os dois atributos no resultado do `TesteStatic` veremos que o `contadorStatic` incrementa e "guarda" a quantidade de vezes em que o construtor foi invocado.

Recomendo fortemente que crie e teste essas duas classes para entender melhor como um atributo static funciona. Também recomendo a leitura e os exercicios desse [link](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/modificadores-de-acesso-e-atributos-de-classe#encapsulamento)